# How to use array of pointers as a instance of class

Tags: c++

I would like to use array pointer as instance of class.
for example:

```
char *pArray[100];
pArray[1] = &class_name; //pArray[1] has the address of "class_name" class.


cout<<"Name Property: %s Age Property: %d"<<pArray[1].name<<pArray[1].age);
```

Comment: **What** do you want to do? Store pointers to objects in an array of `char` pointers? Use memory from array as a storage for object? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to cast the element to a `class_name` pointer:

```
(class_name*)pArray[1]
```

and access members with the `->` operator.

```
((class_name*)pArray[1])->name
```

But FYI, this seems wrong. Why not just have an array of `class_name*`, or, better yet, a `std::vector<class_name*>`?

Comment: It seems very wrong to me. Casting pointer types around, while possible, is only very occasionally actually useful. All the rest of the time it tends to cause both horrible confusion and potentially very hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: There is array of strings in the question, so how your answer relates? The whole question is well messed and should be corrected.

Comment: @mloskot seems pretty clear to me. He has an array of `class_name` pointers which he stores in an array of `char` pointers.

Comment: @user1341970 because in the function you're taking the address of a temporary.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore Still it doesnt seems well. i have tried to do that http://pastebin.com/tXEPrznz
and i got error message "IntelliSense: expected a ';'"

Comment: @user1341970 you're not passing an array. Now you're passing a reference. It should be `void func2(class_name* obj)`.

Comment: unfortunately my function has to be without any parameters. so what i should do for god's sake?

Comment: @user1341970 your function has parameters as it is.

Comment: I solve this problem! I have created a instance in the class and use it

Comment: @LuchianGrigore not really, see the comment: address of "class_name" class. It does not say anything what type of class_name is, is it a string of characters storing name of class or object of some other type. The question is incomplete and pure quality.

Comment: @mloskot have you looked at the code in the comments: `void func(class_name &obj)`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Are you answering the question or the comments. The question is of pure quality, I repeat.